# Cakephp json output: Unable to store and output UTF8 character using _serialize key

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I am using cakephp json view. Using _serialize key to output my parameters. Currently, everything works perfectly. However, when it comes to a UTF8 character(chinese character), _serialize key output my character as other string. 
I've added encoding => 'UTF8' in my database config file. 
Any idea how can i get _serialize to output chinese character?

Comment: please visit the following link:http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Since you don't give an example, I assume you're viewing ``_serialize`` output directly. It is normal for your character to be displayed as another string because it needs to be turned from multibyte to single byte. Once you de-serialize the same string it will turn back to UTF8.